# Print report pages in different files providing filenames dynamically

Tags: c#, java, ms-access, reporting

I have come across a challenging requirement for Reports and Printing of reports. The requirement is : Create a report (lets say 5 pages), each page should be saved in different files with providing the filename dynamically (using record id on that page) through the code.

Currently, I tried with Access and VBA, I could get the report of X pages, but fail to save each page of the report in separate files. How do I accomplish this ?

Can any other technology help me achieve this goal - maybe programming in C# or Java help me? I've been stuck on this for 3 days on this.

Thanks

My Access Code and the problem :

```
Private Sub Report_Click()
 Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim MyFilename As String
Dim MyPath As String
Dim temp As String
Set db = CurrentDb
MyPath = "c:\temp\"
Dim stremp As String
stremp = "select distinct(empno) from query2"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(stremp)
Do While Not rs.EOF
    temp = rs("Empno")
    MyFilename = rs("EMPNO") & ".PDF"
    DoCmd.OpenReport "FORM", acViewReport, "EMPNO" = " & temp"
    'DoCmd.OpenReport "form", acViewPreview, , "empno", acWindowNormal
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, MyPath & MyFilename
    'do.cmd.outputto
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "FORM"
     DoEvents
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
 End Sub
```

The recordset has 5 records i.e. 5 pages. It prints 5 times 5 pages i.e. for Record1 I get all 5 recrods, Record2 - all 5 records & so on. Instead I should create only 1 for Record1, 1 for Record2 and so on.

Can anyone help me know where my code is wrong/improper.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Access?

Comment: MS Access 2010. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can split task to:

1. generate full report as one file
2. store every page of report as different files.

If you already complete first part, and if you can store your report as pdf file, for second part i can suggest to use `iText`. It is java library, but has port to c# too.

Small example:

```
    String folder = "/home/user/report/";
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(folder + "test.pdf");
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(is);

    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        File tmp = new File(folder + "out" + i +".pdf");
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(tmp);
        Document pdDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdDoc, outStream);
        pdDoc.open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
        pdDoc.newPage();
        cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        pdDoc.close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This really helps me. I also got to add digital signature to the page that I split. Wondering for the same. Can you help me know, why my code of Access doesn't do the job. Pls see the code above.

Comment: Thanks. this really worked. I want to sign on the last page of the pdf. I can know the number of pages through reader, but from the above eg that you showed link, in that type of code how do I set to sign on last page. Finding hard any resource on net for the same. Can you guide me.

Comment: @Tvd there is SO, feel free to ask question. If you show some effort and code, many good people can help you. Sure i can help a bit too, but your new question is really not related to this one.

Comment: Yes, surely. I was figuring out the same and finally got the solution to it too. We can set the number of page in createSignature() 3rd parameter. Thanks a lot. I had asked other Q reg Sin on page at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218203/sign-pdf-file-on-last-page?noredirect=1#comment24943347_17218203

Answer (score 1):

> Can you help me know, why my code of Access doesn't do the job.

This statement has problems:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "FORM", acViewReport, "EMPNO" = " & temp"
```

The third argument of `DoCmd.OpenReport` is `[FilterName]` which is "A string expression that's the valid name of a query in the current database." Unfortunately,

```
"EMPNO" = " & temp"
```

is a boolean expression that will always be `False` because the two strings are not equal. I think you had something more like this in mind:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "FORM", acViewReport, , "EMPNO = " & temp
```

where the fourth argument, `[WhereCondition]`, is "A string expression that's a valid SQL WHERE clause without the word WHERE."

Comment: Thanks Gord. But even after removing ", from the code their is no difference in the results. It still gives the same output.

Comment: @Tvd Did you add the extra comma too? (I put two commas between `acViewReport` and `"EMPNO ..."`.)

Comment: Oh Gord, Thanks a lot. It did the work. I want to add digital signature (pfx file) in the report. Is that possible in Access reporting. If adding digital signature is handled then I will not require report to be created in code in C# using iTextSharp.

Comment: @Tvd RE: "I want to add digital signature (pfx file) in the report. Is that possible in Access reporting." - I've never tried so I don't really know, but I sort of doubt it.

Comment: Thanks a lord Gord Thompson.